# kde frontend for apt

Tags: debian, kde, package-management, aptitude

I'm recently installed kde in debian testing in my laptop, which is a good frontend to apt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back then we used [Adept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adept_Manager), but now the only used (as far as I know) one is [KPackageKit](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/KPackageKit?content=84745). (The former is for KDE3, the later is for KDE4 (and for every system using PackageKit))

Oh Adept still works (the one in testing), it uses KDE4 stuff. Just feel free to install it. As far as I know Debian doesn't ships PackageKit yet. (Maybe 10 years later when everyone switches and it goes stable. :D)

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Synaptic Package Manager](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/)

Answer (score 2):

The default and native to KDE - package manager is KPackageKit. However you can install synaptic package manager as well. However Synaptic is gtk based.

Answer (score 2):

There's a new kid on the block: [Muon](https://launchpad.net/muon/)